Fixed effects regression: reghdfe vs reg with dummies (stata)
I am trying to understand what is the difference between running a regression with a bunch of fixed effects by directly creating the dummies versus using reghdfe. Below a minimal working example:
 sysuse auto
 reghdfe price i.turn, absorb(foreign)
 reg price i.turn i.foreign

The coefficients on i.turn are the same using the two approaches. But the constant is very different. What is the reason for this? What is the interpretation of each constant?
Results are below:
reghdfe price i.turn, absorb(foreign)
(MWFE estimator converged in 1 iterations)

HDFE Linear regression                            Number of obs   =         74
Absorbing 1 HDFE group                            F(  17,     55) =       1.86
                                                  Prob > F        =     0.0425
                                                  R-squared       =     0.3669
                                                  Adj R-squared   =     0.1598
                                                  Within R-sq.    =     0.3654
                                                  Root MSE        =  2703.6495

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        turn |
         32  |  -2361.476   3987.088    -0.59   0.556    -10351.78    5628.827
         33  |  -1535.238   3359.157    -0.46   0.649     -8267.14    5196.664
         34  |  -974.9838   3015.917    -0.32   0.748    -7019.016    5069.048
         35  |   -1492.65   3015.917    -0.49   0.623    -7536.682    4551.381
         36  |  -1092.201   3021.794    -0.36   0.719    -7148.011    4963.609
         37  |   1962.012   3075.144     0.64   0.526    -4200.713    8124.738
         38  |   3066.683   3211.548     0.95   0.344    -3369.403    9502.769
         39  |       -675   3823.538    -0.18   0.861    -8337.541    6987.541
         40  |  -129.1667   2920.275    -0.04   0.965    -5981.529    5723.196
         41  |     2310.5   3022.772     0.76   0.448    -3747.271    8368.271
         42  |   467.1429   2890.323     0.16   0.872    -5325.194    6259.479
         43  |    2447.25   2814.048     0.87   0.388    -3192.228    8086.728
         44  |   2699.333   3121.906     0.86   0.391    -3557.105    8955.772
         45  |   4639.667   3121.906     1.49   0.143    -1616.772    10896.11
         46  |   908.6667   3121.906     0.29   0.772    -5347.772    7165.105
         48  |     4982.5   3311.281     1.50   0.138    -1653.455    11618.46
         51  |       6993   3823.538     1.83   0.073    -669.5411    14655.54
             |
       _cons |   5231.331    2724.45     1.92   0.060    -228.5889    10691.25
------------------------------------------------------------------------------




 reg price i.turn i.foreign
    
          Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        74
    -------------+----------------------------------   F(18, 55)       =      1.77
           Model |   233030749        18  12946152.7   Prob > F        =    0.0539
        Residual |   402034647        55  7309720.86   R-squared       =    0.3669
    -------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.1598
           Total |   635065396        73  8699525.97   Root MSE        =    2703.6
    
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price | Coefficient  Std. err.      t    P>|t|     [95% conf. interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        turn |
         32  |  -2361.476   3987.088    -0.59   0.556    -10351.78    5628.827
         33  |  -1535.238   3359.157    -0.46   0.649     -8267.14    5196.664
         34  |  -974.9838   3015.917    -0.32   0.748    -7019.016    5069.048
         35  |   -1492.65   3015.917    -0.49   0.623    -7536.682    4551.381
         36  |  -1092.201   3021.794    -0.36   0.719    -7148.011    4963.609
         37  |   1962.012   3075.144     0.64   0.526    -4200.713    8124.738
         38  |   3066.683   3211.548     0.95   0.344    -3369.403    9502.769
         39  |       -675   3823.538    -0.18   0.861    -8337.541    6987.541
         40  |  -129.1667   2920.275    -0.04   0.965    -5981.529    5723.196
         41  |     2310.5   3022.772     0.76   0.448    -3747.271    8368.271
         42  |   467.1429   2890.323     0.16   0.872    -5325.194    6259.479
         43  |    2447.25   2814.048     0.87   0.388    -3192.228    8086.728
         44  |   2699.333   3121.906     0.86   0.391    -3557.105    8955.772
         45  |   4639.667   3121.906     1.49   0.143    -1616.772    10896.11
         46  |   908.6667   3121.906     0.29   0.772    -5347.772    7165.105
         48  |     4982.5   3311.281     1.50   0.138    -1653.455    11618.46
         51  |       6993   3823.538     1.83   0.073    -669.5411    14655.54
             |
     foreign |
    Foreign  |   2446.476   1130.233     2.16   0.035     181.4379    4711.514
       _cons |       4504    2703.65     1.67   0.101    -914.2348    9922.235
------------------------------------------------------------------------------


You should explain that you're using Stata. I am a long-term Stata user but have never used reghdfe. How much sense this makes to anyone who doesn't use Stata and/or is not familiar with this kind of model I can't guess.

That is fair. I thought I had added the stata tag. Will do so now.

In R I get
> mean(auto$foreign)*2446.5+4504
[1] 5231.338

so it looks as though reghdfe is estimating the intercept at the mean value of foreign and regress is estimating it at foreign==0
